# Trigger not working as expected

Tags: trigger

I'm new to triggers I create a trigger to update lookup field on a custom object but when I use it with a bulk update, insert the records missed up in the list, Kindly find the trigger below and help with what should be done to solve the issue.
Thanks

```java
trigger UpdateaccID on Account_updates__c (before insert, before update) {

    List<String> Acc = new List<String>(); 
    for (Account_updates__c obj: trigger.new){
        Acc.add(obj.Account__c);
    }

    List<Account_Loader_vod__c> acctATLlist = [select id,Account_vod__c from Account_Territory_vod__c where Account_vod__c in :Acc];

    if (acctATLlist.size() > 0 ){

        for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++)
        {

            if (Trigger.new[i].Account__c!= null)  
            {
                Trigger.new[i].ATL__c = acctATLlist[i].ID; 
            }   
            else
            {
                Trigger.new[i].ATL__c = null;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What you want to ahcieve from your trigger ?

Comment: if both accounts match in both object, update the first object with the second object lookup field. if I use bulk insert the lookup get the ids wrong . I think because of the match work on the whole list not account level. if I use it on single record it works fine ... hope this clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a map to get the correct record:

```
List<Id> Acc = new List<Id>(); 
for (Account_updates__c obj: trigger.new){
    Acc.add(obj.Account__c);
}
Map<Id, Id> accvod = new Map<Id, Id>();
for(Account_Territory_vod__c record: [select Account_vod__c from Account_Territory_vod__c where Account_vod__c in :Acc]) {
  accvod.put(record.Account_Vod__c, record.Id);
}
for(Account_updates__c record: trigger.new) {
  record.ATL__c = accvod.get(record.Account__c);
}
```